# Splitting a string in Python based on a regex pattern

Tags: regex, string, list, python-3.6

I have a **bytes** object that contains urls:

```
> body.decode("utf-8") 
> 'https://www.wired.com/story/car-news-roundup-tesla-model-3-sales/\r\n\r\nhttps://cleantechnica.com/2018/11/11/can-you-still-get-the-7500-tax-credit-on-a-tesla-model-3-maybe-its-complicated/\r\n'
```

I need to split it into a list with each url as a separate element:

```
import re
pattern = '^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$'

urls = re.compile(pattern).split(body.decode("utf-8"))
```

What I get is a list of one element with all urls pasted together:

```
['https://www.wired.com/story/car-news-roundup-tesla-model-3-sales/\r\n\r\nhttps://cleantechnica.com/2018/11/11/can-you-still-get-the-7500-tax-credit-on-a-tesla-model-3-maybe-its-complicated/\r\n']
```

How do I split each url into a separate element?

Comment: Why don't you split with \s+? That should give you required results.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi can you give an example?

Comment: Its probably because you're pattern doesn't match anything, so it doesn't split anything.

Comment: You'd be better off using a _findall()_ kind of thing using a modified pattern of yours `(?m)^(?:https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?`

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting it with `\s+`

Try this sample python code,

```
import re
s = 'https://www.wired.com/story/car-news-roundup-tesla-model-3-sales/\r\n\r\nhttps://cleantechnica.com/2018/11/11/can-you-still-get-the-7500-tax-credit-on-a-tesla-model-3-maybe-its-complicated/\r\n'
urls = re.compile('\s+').split(s)
print(urls)
```

This outputs,

```
['https://www.wired.com/story/car-news-roundup-tesla-model-3-sales/', 'https://cleantechnica.com/2018/11/11/can-you-still-get-the-7500-tax-credit-on-a-tesla-model-3-maybe-its-complicated/', '']
```

Does this result looks ok? Or we can work on it and make as you desire.

In case you don't want empty string ('') in your result list (because of \r\n in the end), you can use find all to find all the URLs in your string. Sample python code for same is following,

```
import re
s = 'https://www.wired.com/story/car-news-roundup-tesla-model-3-sales/\r\n\r\nhttps://cleantechnica.com/2018/11/11/can-you-still-get-the-7500-tax-credit-on-a-tesla-model-3-maybe-its-complicated/\r\n'
urls = re.findall('http.*?(?=\s+)', s)
print(urls)
```

This gives following output,

```
['https://www.wired.com/story/car-news-roundup-tesla-model-3-sales/', 'https://cleantechnica.com/2018/11/11/can-you-still-get-the-7500-tax-credit-on-a-tesla-model-3-maybe-its-complicated/']
```

Comment: You have all the URLs in urls array, you can use them the way you want. I am not sure what you mean by "put each url into a separate element of a list"?